# Let $G$ be a group. If there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $a^m=1$ for all $a\in G$, then is $G$ finite?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Let $G$ be a group. If there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $a^m=1$ for all $a\in G$, then is $G$ finite? That is, all elements should have order that divides the fixed integer $m$. (The set of orders of elements of $G$ is a finite set.)

I have no idea how to prove or disprove this statement. Is there any counterexample for this?

Comment: I have considered the example of the set of roots of unity in $\mathcal{C}$, but the problem is a bit different. The problem demands that all elements should have order that divides the fixed integer $m$.

Comment: Then have a look at Brian's answer with $G=(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^\omega$ at the duplicate, or $G=H^\omega$ with $|H|=m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $(\mathbb{Z}_2[x],+)$? Every element has order $2$.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your enlightening example!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.